# Word 365 VBA event when 'Edit Document' is clicked

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

In Word 2016 documents could be modified from VBA despite read-only. We used to update a status label (Offline, Draft, .., Completed, Replaced) in header (with the Document Open event), but this is not possible in 365 desktop - until `Edit Document` is clicked (or `LockServerFile`) -by permitted users.

No event seems to exist to run code when 'Edit Document' is clicked.
Any ideas?

Application and Document events for this doesn't exist.

The `Edit Anyway` appears if edited manually while readonly, -this could be a better way.. if possible from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely add, delete or modify custom document properties in a read-only document. Perhaps it would be easiest to have a custom document property and have a field in the header.

```
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties(PropertyName).Value = "Draft"
```

After that, just update the field in the header for the user, which also works in read-only mode.

```
Public Sub UpdateHeader()
Dim MySec As Word.Section
Dim FirstUpdate As Boolean ' Flag for the loop if any header has been updated yet - makes sure at least the first one gets updated and only linked ones after that are skipped

For Each MySec In ActiveDocument.Sections
    If Not FirstUpdate Or Not MySec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious Then ' Execute the update on the first header and any header that is not linked to previous
        MySec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Fields.Update
    End If
    FirstUpdate = True
Next MySec
End Sub
```

Comment: That's a good solution - for future documents, but not applicable to the 70.000 existing documents. A PowerApp is about to replace the system.